# CNN model converges very fast

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I am training a CNN model with text dataset(domain names) of 1 million entries. The model seem to converge very fast. Gives me 94% accuracy in just 1 epoch. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
def build_model(max_features, maxlen):
    """Build CNN model"""
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(max_features, 8, input_length=maxlen))
    model.add(Convolution1D(6, 4, border_mode='same'))
    model.add(Convolution1D(4, 4, border_mode='same'))
    model.add(Convolution1D(2, 4, border_mode='same'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    #model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    #model.add(Dense(2,activation='sigmoid'))
    #model.add(Dense(180,activation='sigmoid'))
    #model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))

    return model
```

Output During first 3 epochs:

```
950000/950000 [==============================] - 232s - loss: 0.1764 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9356 - fmeasure: 0.9356 - precision: 0.9356 - recall: 0.9356 - val_loss: 0.1579 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.9418 - val_fmeasure: 0.9418 - val_precision: 0.9418 - val_recall: 0.9418
Epoch 2/3
950000/950000 [==============================] - 232s - loss: 0.1567 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9450 - fmeasure: 0.9450 - precision: 0.9450 - recall: 0.9450 - val_loss: 0.1518 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.9489 - val_fmeasure: 0.9489 - val_precision: 0.9489 - val_recall: 0.9489
Epoch 3/3
950000/950000 [==============================] - 232s - loss: 0.1515 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9474 - fmeasure: 0.9474 - precision: 0.9474 - recall: 0.9474 - val_loss: 0.1474 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.9472 - val_fmeasure: 0.9472 - val_precision: 0.9472 - val_recall: 0.9472
3392/3801 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s[0.15151389103144666, 0.94817153352462946, 0.94817148384625149, 0.94817153391666209, 0.94817153391666209]
```

Comment: Do you have other metrics to share, such as [precision and recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall)? Can you tell more about the dataset, is it well-balanced or does it have a significant imbalance?

Comment: The data is well balanced. During the first epoch, AUC is 0.96

Comment: I have updated the question with precision and recall values. Please refer. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can tell, the network is learning to solve the problem. My best guess regarding the high accuracy after a single epoch is that the problem is quite easy for this model to solve. You could verify this by simplifying the model, it should learn more slowly.

Comment: Do you have separate validation samples to test the real-world performance of the network? If yes, when passing these samples to the trained network, is the accuracy equally high? If not, the network probably already overfitted in the first epoch (which might be a problem).

Comment: Thanks Marrten for you sugguestion, How do you I should simplify the model? Should I reduce the number of convolution layers?

Comment: Yes I have separated validation and test dataset and the model is giving good accuracy as well. But the problem is when I introduce a new data sample  (with unseen pattern in the training dataset) the model seem to be biased and it gives high probability(0.999) to be classified as one class or the other

Comment: You could take out one or two of the convolution layers. Or alternatively, you could try to lower the learning rate (cut it to 1/10th or 1/100th of the current value), that should also make the network learn more slowly. Also note that high accuracy is not a bad thing, it is interesting to analyze why the accuracy is increasing so rapidly; but in the end, you definitely want a model that predicts accurately. ;)

Comment: If the network fails to classify unseen samples correctly, it might already be heavily overfitted. Definitely lower the learning rate in that case. What is the learning rate you used? I would try 0.001 or 0.0001 (or even lower if the learning rate you used is already this low). Dropout layers are also a measure against overfitting, so definitely put those layers back in when faced with an overfitted network.

Comment: Current learning rate is 0.01. I will try as you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: I am still getting high accuracy while training and the model seem to give biased results for unseen samples. many unseen samples are classified wrongly with 100% confidence (probability-1).

Comment: Definitely try to simplify the model in that case.

Comment: How many samples exist in each class?

Comment: 5000000 samples in each class